# Grunt Require optimization - Backbone is not defined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs, marionette

I've built a Marionette / Requirejs application and am trying to optimise it. Once compiled and tested in the browser i get an error "Backbone is not defined".

**Edit**

I read that making the mainConfigFile = my main.js file from the require project solves these types of issues, though when i try add that and remove all the path info from the gruntfile i get a grunt compile error that my main.js file isnt valid JSON.

**End Edit**

Heres my gruntfile.js requirejs config:

```
requirejs: {
      compile: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: "scripts",
            paths: {
                requireLib: 'lib/require',
                templates: '../templates',
                underscore: 'lib/underscore',
                backbone: 'lib/backbone',
                jquery: 'lib/jquery',
                backbonevalidation: 'lib/backbone-validation',
                marionette: 'lib/backbone.marionette',
                json2: 'lib/json2',
                text: 'lib/text',
                errorlogger: 'lib/errorlogger',
                moment: 'lib/moment.min',
                glossary: 'lib/glossary',
                facebook: '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all',
                "codebird": 'lib/codebird',
                "cryptojs": 'lib/md5',
                jquerySteps: 'lib/jquery.steps',
                JQValidate: 'lib/jquery.validate.min',
                numeral: 'lib/numeral',
                async: 'lib/async',
                homeloanAmort: 'lib/homeloanamortisation',
                financial: 'lib/financial',
                bonds: 'lib/finance/bonds',
                common: 'lib/finance/common',
                daycountbasis: 'lib/finance/daycountbasis',
                depreciation: 'lib/finance/depreciation',
                irr: 'lib/finance/irr',
                loan: 'lib/finance/loan',
                misc: 'lib/finance/misc',
                oddbonds: 'lib/finance/oddbonds',
                tbill: 'lib/finance/tbill',
                tvm: 'lib/finance/tvm',
                retirementneeds: 'lib/retirementneeds',
                numeral: 'lib/numeral',
                carloanamortisation: 'lib/carloanamortisation',
                carleasebuy: 'lib/carleasevsbuy',
                cookie: 'lib/jquery.cookie',
                homerentvsbuy: 'lib/homerentvsbuy',
                "JQstorageapi": 'lib/jquery.storageapi.min',
                regiontransitions: 'lib/region-transitions'
            },

            shim : {
                underscore: {
                    exports: '_'
                },
                backbone: {
                    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                    exports: 'Backbone'
                },
                backbonevalidation: {
                    deps: ['backbone'],
                    exports: 'Backbone'
                },
                marionette: {
                    deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
                    exports: 'Marionette'
                },
                errorlogger: {
                    deps: ['jquery']
                },
                numeral: {
                    exports: "numeral"
                },
                jquerySteps: {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                    exports: "Steps"
                },
                JQValidate: {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                    exports: "JQValidate"
                },
                JQstorageapi: {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                    exports: "JQstorageapi"
                },
                facebook: {
                    exports: 'FB'
                },
                cryptojs: {
                    exports: 'CryptoJS'
                },
                financial: {
                    deps: ['bonds','common','daycountbasis','depreciation','irr','loan','misc','oddbonds','tbill','tvm'],
                    exports :'financial'
                }
            },

            baseUrl : "scripts",
            name: "main",
            out: "optimised/js/main.min.js",
            removeCombined: true,
            include: ["requireLib", 'main.js'],
            out: "optimised/js/main.min.js",
            findNestedDependencies: true
        }
      }
    },
```

I'm going wrong somewhere, and with some searching around i know it has to do with the Shim, paths, and using AMD modules. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: http://jrburke.com/2014/02/16/requirejs-2.1.11-released/

**Solution**

Adding `wrapShim: true,` to the gruntfile require config solved it.